# Remote execute sql script for one server to another

Tags: sql-server, powershell, invoke, sqlcmd

I have a "test.sql" in Server1, and I would like to run this script on server2 and server3. I utilized the code below:

```
$InstanceNm = "server2\inst2,1433"

$CommandExecute_SP = "D:\testscript\test.sql" --located in Server1

invoke-expression "SQLCMD -E -S $InstanceNm -d 'master' -i  $CommandExecute_SP -b"
```

I run the all the codes from server1 and I target server2, but I am getting this error:

```
SQLCMD : Sqlcmd: 'server2\inst2,1433': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

Then when i type `-?`
It gives this:

```
At line:1 char:2
+ -?
+  ~
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2
+ -?
+  ~
Unexpected token '?' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

I was wondering what the correct way is to run a .sql file which creates objects on another server from a separate server? I know how to run short sql statements via using `System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection` but I would like to avoid that since this .sql file has over 1000 lines of code.

Comment: Should the test.sql file also be copied to server2?

Comment: `"$InstanceNm"`

Answer (score 0):

You could create remote sessions and run the command via `Invoke-Command`-cmdlet.

```
$sessions = New-PSSession -computername server1, server2, server3 
invoke-command -session $sessions -scriptblock {
   invoke-expression "SQLCMD -E -S $InstanceNm -d 'master' -i  $CommandExecute_SP -b"
}
```

If you've Win2012 R2 (or higher version) PS-remoting is activated by default. Otherwise take a look at [remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I ran through myscript again and found out that the error was caused by the ' character in the 'master', I omitted this and it is working now.